# Difference between audio encoding/decoding and format conversion

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, core-audio

Recently i have been trying to convert an audio file from one format to another through ffmpeg. i was trying to do some google but results made me a little confused about the difference between encoding and decoding an audio file and converting from one format to another.

Comment: Also see [What is a Codec (e.g. DivX?), and how does it differ from a File Format (e.g. MPG)?](http://superuser.com/a/300997/110524)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me describe it this way: There are several different *file formats* for video files (sometimes also called "wrappers"). There are also several different *codecs* which can be used to encode (or compress) the audio and video. Audio and video use different codecs - and the encoded formats can be sorted in different file types/formats.

So when you talk about "encoding" vs. "converting" a couple of things come into play.

"Encoding" would be the act of taking audio/video and encoding them into a given codec(s). "Converting" implies having stuff in one format, but wanting it in another. There are two ways of looking at this:

1. Often called "repackaging" - this is when the video (for example) has been encoded correctly (let's say h264, with a bunch of parameters), but you want it in a different file-type - maybe it's an .AVI and you wanted it in an .MP4. This doesn't involve changing the actual video - just re-wraping the h264 stream in a new "wrapper", and is thus a fast operation.
2. Re-encoding. Let's say your audio was in a MP3 format, and you wanted it in an AAC format. This would require decoding the entire MP3 stream, and re-encoding it into AAC.

Obviously you can also do "1" and "2" together.

Refer [Formats](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html) and [Codecs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html)   for detailed information.

Hope it helps!